# create a JavaScript object dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a calendar using `AngularJS`, and my model is an object like this:

```
$scope.model = {
        weeks: [
                {
                    days: [
                    null,
                    {
                        name: "3 dec",
                        toDoItems: [{ name: "Task 1" }, { name: "Task 2"}]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "4 dec",
                        toDoItems: [{name: "Task 1"}, {name: "Task 2"}]
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                    days: [
                    null,
                    {
                        name: "5 dec",
                        toDoItems: [{ name: "Task 1" }, { name: "Task 2"}]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "6 dec",
                        toDoItems: [{name: "Task 1"}, {name: "Task 2"}]
                    }
                ]
                }

            ]
           }
```

But I want to create the object dynamically.

I've tried something like this, but it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined



 $scope.fillMonth = function () {
        var gap = dayInWeek($scope.year.value, $scope.month, 1),
            nrOfDays = daysInMonth($scope.year.value, $scope.month);

        $scope.model = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < (nrOfDays + gap) % 7; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (j === 0)
                    $scope.model.weeks.push([]);

                if (i === 0 && j < gap)
                    $scope.model.weeks[i].days.push(null);

                else
                    $scope.model.weeks[i].days.push([{ name: i + ' ' + j, toDoItems: [{ name: "Task 1" }, { name: "Task 2"}]}]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is that `weeks` does not exist. You need to create it first like so:

```
$scope.model = {};//new object
$scope.model.weeks = [];//new array
```

After that you do not want to push an empty array, instead push a new object that contains a days array:

```
var weeksObj = {};//new object
weeksObj.days = [];//new array
$scope.model.weeks.push(weeksObj);
```

You can then push your days values like so, for null:

```
weeksObj.days.push(null);
```

and for your days object, again create a new object:

```
var dayObj = {};//new object
dayObj.name = "name";//set name property
dayObj.toDoItems = [];//new array
weeksObj.days.push(dayObj);
```

Hopefully that will help you see where your problems are. It seems you are getting mixed up a bit between an object (`{}`) and an array (`[]`). Only arrays have the push method

Answer (score 1):

In your loop do not push an empty array but set weeks to an empty array. and do not forget to create first object with day

```
    for (var i = 0; i < (nrOfDays + gap) % 7; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (j === 0)
                $scope.model.weeks = [];

            if (i === 0 && j < gap)
                $scope.model.weeks[i] = {day: [null]};

            else
                $scope.model.weeks[i].days.push([{ name: i + ' ' + j, toDoItems: [{ name: "Task 1" }, { name: "Task 2"}]}]);
        }
    }
```